# Graphic SVG in html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, vector

I´m trying to put in my HTML a SVG vector graphic.

This SVG: http://webkunst.comeze.com/graphic.svg

I managed to load it thru like this:

```
<embed src="images/grafica-2.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>
```

the problem is that it just loads the file, but I need that I can modify the percentages of each color. I mean, that I can control thru the html the data of the svg, not just importing the svg "closed".

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Frameworks like [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) and [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) allow you to create and modify SVGs. There are plenty of examples for each of them.